# nested join in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

Folks, what is wrong with this query i get error stating below in DB2 LUW.

> [42703][-206] "d.sales" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.23.42 [56098][-727] An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-206", SQLSTATE "42703" and message tokens "d.sales".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.23.42

```
SELECT listagg(e.name,';'), e.address,d.sales
FROM emp e
JOIN (
    SELECT distinct sales, org
    FROM sales s
    JOIN address a ON S.ID = a.id
) d ON d.salesid = e.salesid
```

Comment: `d` does not contain a column named `salesid` so this cannot work : `ON d.salesid = e.salesid `

Comment: You would need to show us sample data and expected output so we can try to help with the query. As it is, we are just guessing.

Comment: It's obviously that `s.salesid` or `a.salesid` is forgotten in subquery

Comment: @AlexYu : adding an additional field to the subquery might affect the results of the outer query, since `DISTINCT` is used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your query:

```
SELECT listagg(e.name,';'), e.address,d.sales
FROM emp e
JOIN (SELECT distinct sales, org  -- you need to add salesid to your columns set
         FROM sales s
         JOIN address a ON S.ID = a.id
) d ON d.salesid = e.salesid
```

You forgot to select `salesid` in your subquery `d`

You need to add either `s.salesid` or `a.salesid`

Comment: Adding an additional field to the subquery might affect the results of the outer query, since `DISTINCT` is used...

Comment: Yes. I absolutely agree with you. That's why knowledge of `sales` or `address` tables is needed

Answer (score 0):

apparently i made up a bad example, as i cant past the actual query. I think you all are right it is missing column.